# Insert text inside stanza at the end of the data string

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, text-formatting

I have a file I need to echo text into at the end of the file from the command line, the problem is the data is in a stanza, all within curly braces.

This is the end of the file:

```
text-string1,text-string2,text-string3;
}
```

I need to be able to insert text after text-string3, but still keep it inside the semi-colon and brace. Like this:

```
text-string1,text-string2,text-string3,new-text-string;
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish this from command line?

Answer (score 2):

Can be done e.g. with single `sed` but for a sake of simplicity I would use `tac`:

```
tac file | sed '2s/;$/new-text-string;/' | tac
```

Comment: I need this to be an in place change, not sent to stdout.

Comment: Ok I just used your sed statement and removed the "2". -- sed -i 's/;$/,new-text-string;/' filename

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/;$/,new-text-string;/' filename
```

Will find the last occurrance of the ";" and append the new data before it. The -i makes it an in place change to the file from the command line.